# Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated on empty lines of code

Tags: php, deprecated

I know that this question has been answered many times, but I have some problem that I can't fix.
I got several warnings about Assining the return value on specific pages and specific line. But when I opet that page, either the requested line is empty, under comments or something else.. 
Here's one warning and page code that goes with it:

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   /home/saltushr/public_html/_classes/hr/dimedia/framework/Controller.class.php
>   on line 25
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   /home/saltushr/public_html/_classes/hr/dimedia/framework/Controller.class.php
>   on line 26

and code is:

```
<?php
/**
 * This clas instantiates the required {@link Model} and {@link View} objects.
 *
 * @author Berislav Lopac berislav.lopac@dimedia.hr 
 * @version 1.0
 */
class Controller {
    var $model;   
    var $view;

    /**
     * The constructor.
     * Instantiates the {@link Model} and {@link View} objects.
     *
     * @param $_task    A String setting the base name of the instantiated objects.
     * @param $_db      ADOConnection object containing the connection to the database.
     * @param $_input   An Array with the input values required by the Model (usually the $_REQUEST array).
     */
    function &Controller($_name, &$_db, $_input) {

        $model = $_name . "Model";
        $view  = $_name . "View";
        $this->model =& new $model($_db, $_input);
        $this->view  =& new $view($this->model);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the associated {@link View} object.
     * @return View
     */
    function &getView() {
        return $this->view;
    }
}
?>
```

as you can see, line 25 and 26 are empty:

> 21 var $model; 
>    22 
>    23 var $view; 
>    24 
>    **25 
>
>    26** 
>    27 /**

Can anyone help me understand what is this all about? I'm quite new at understanding PHP, and could use some help.
Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I messed up the line number reference after formatting the code... but that many empty lines was just horrible.

Comment: You should read the manual before using references: http://php.net/references

Comment: I know, the problem is that this code isn't mine.. I just wanted to remove that Deprecated warnings. I suceeded on 3 pages, but this one is bugging me.

@Felix Kling, ty for removing empty lines, I would do that earlyer to. There is just one problem, when I make anychange to the code I got :

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in /home/saltushr/public_html/_classes/hr/dimedia/framework/Controller.class.php on line 1

... even when I just copy that above code without extra empty lines..

Comment: OK, I worked it out.. deleted every comment and empty line and then put class Controller{ in first line next to <?php tag.. it works now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$this->model =& new $model($_db, $_input);

$this->view  =& new $view($this->model);
```

to

```
$this->model =new $model($_db, $_input);

$this->view  =new $view($this->model);
```

Comment: I know about that, but when I make change to that line of code I got new error regarding the same page:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in /home/saltushr/public_html/_classes/hr/dimedia/framework/Controller.class.php on line 1

And I have read that it has somethin to do with missing "}" or some other errors, but I can't find anything..

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a new instance as a reference, by design this is not a good solution. Instead, pass the objects as reference whenever an object is requesting the specific resource (e.g your `getView`method).

Some objects has to hold the initial instances.